# facter does not show some information

Tags: puppet

I'm using facter to get some information for some bash scripts.
When I run `facter` by itself, it shows me items such as serialnumber and productname.
But when I run `facter serialnumber` or `facter productname`, I get nothing.
Any ideas?

```
myhost:/tmp # facter
facterversion => 1.5.2
operatingsystem => SLES
productname => IBM System x3200 M2 -[4367AC1]-
puppetversion => 2.6.12
rubyversion => 1.8.7
serialnumber => KQABCDE
virtual => physical

myhost:/tmp # facter facterversion
1.5.2
myhost:/tmp # facter rubyversion
1.8.7
myhost:/tmp # facter operatingsystem
SLES
myhost:/tmp # facter productname
myhost:/tmp # facter puppetversion
2.6.12
myhost:/tmp # facter serialnumber
myhost:/tmp # facter virtual
physical
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug in the 1.5.x branch of Facter.  I can't recall the exact version it was fixed in, but a more recent 1.6.x version will fix the issue.